# Least squares, what are the new points?

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

Let's say I have the following equation system:
[equation system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeAeG.png)

The points are graphed as follows:
[graph of points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08zQi.png)

Using the least squares method a solution is x =3 and y=1.

According to the solution manual the purpose of the method is to minimise the distance between between the left side and the right hand side of the equation system.
This results in:
[Squared difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jnfam.png)

When I substitute the values x=3 and y=1 into the equation system the graph I get is:
[new graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tQgd.png)
I thought the new points should be on a line.

My question is:

What is the equation of the line the least squares method results in, or the new points corresponding to each old point?

Comment: One cannot help you without knowing where you are stuck. If you don't show what you already have done your question might be closed. First explain how you got the graph of points from the equation system.

Comment: All questions on this site should be self contained. Please make use of [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) wherever necessary and avoid redirecting readers to multiple links.